# startWith with regex kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I see that start with in Kotlin is only accepting CharSequence and no regex

How do I match regex with start with in Kotlin?

Comment: A `^` anchor will make the usual regex `find()` method only look for a match at the start of a string (if a multiline option is used, at the start of a line). To only match at the start of the string, use `\A`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! That worked